# raster package in R not recognizing a .bil file

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I normally load .bil files into R using the `raster` package in R like this:

```
require(raster)
require(rgdal)

my.layer<- raster('path/to/file.bil')
```

This general code is working on one of my computers just fine. However, when running this on my cluster I get an error:

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
  `/path/to/file.bil' not recognised as a supported file format.


Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
```

I can't figure out whats going wrong here. Same error on multiple raster files that load fine on my other computer. I am running R version 3.1.2 and the following package versions:

```
rgdal_0.8-16     raster_2.2-31    sp_1.0-15
```

Comment: What does `gdalDrivers()` show in the `EHdr` row? Can you read in other raster formats on the cluster?

Comment: @jbaums `gdalDrivers()` reads `EHdr                                       ESRI .hdr Labelled   TRUE  TRUE`. I've gotten it to load a `.asc` file, but it failed when I used the `extract` function to grab data from the layer for a set of points. The error read: `Error: Failure during raster IO`

Comment: `file.exists('path/to/file.hdr')`?

Comment: @RobertH its a .bil, rather than a .hdr, but yes it exists. Prints: `> file.exists('required_products_utilities/PRISM.tmean.30yr.normal.4kmM2.annual.bil')
[1] TRUE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `.bil` file cannot be correctly interpreted when the header file is absent. This is a file with the same name, but with extension `.hdr`.

Comment: okay. So do I have to reference the `.hdr` file in the raster function? Not sure how to include the `.hdr` file. I have it in the directory.

Comment: It just needs to be there

Comment: working on this now. Is there a particular name format the `.hdr` file needs? For instance if I am trying to load `cool_file.bil`, does the `.hdr` file need to be labeled `cool_file.hdr` or can it be `cool_file_bil.hdr` or whatever?

Comment: This is the problem: if you have `cool_file.bil`, then your corresponding `.hdr` file MUST be named `cool_file.hdr`

Comment: Indeed, otherwise it would be impossible to know which files go together